# Pine script - using buy limit/sell limit is not firing at an exact price

Tags: pine-script-v5

I am trying to enter using a buy limit order at an exact price using pine script eg. 146.090 but even though the price has gone under and over it - it still does not execute.

I do not want to use close/high/low etc, just the exact price.

It would be greatly appreciated if somebody had a workaround for the issue.

Thx.

```
    //@version=5

    VERSION = "V1"
    SCRIPT_NAME = "Test " + VERSION

    InitCapital = 100000
    InitPosition = 100.0
    InitCommission = 0.025
    InitPyramidMax = 1
    CalcOnorderFills = false
    ProcessOrdersOnClose = true
    CalcOnEveryTick = true
    CloseEntriesRule = "FIFO"

    strategy(title=SCRIPT_NAME, shorttitle=SCRIPT_NAME, overlay=true, pyramiding=InitPyramidMax, initial_capital=InitCapital, default_qty_type=strategy.fixed, process_orders_on_close=ProcessOrdersOnClose, default_qty_value=InitPosition, commission_type=strategy.commission.percent, calc_on_order_fills=CalcOnorderFills, calc_on_every_tick=CalcOnEveryTick, precision=9, max_lines_count=500, max_labels_count=500, commission_value=InitCommission)

    var float entry = 145.606

    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, limit=entry)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace :

```
strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, limit=entry)
```

By :

```
strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, limit=entry, close=entry)
```